# Circle in my graph, get the nodes from the circle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, extjs, graph

I have some 'random' graph: some nodes have some connections, some have not, and it can be, my graph has one or more circle in it.

I need to get the nodes of the circle: for example i have this node (A). 'A' is in circle? And what are the nodes of this circle, in what 'A' is?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Do a depth first traversal DFS. Initially all nodes are white. When exploring a give node, mark it grey. When done mark it black. Only visit nodes which are white. If you encounter grey node, there is your cycle. You can read more about DFS on web. e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search